# Why does the Daemon keep flipping about after full loading

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, synchronization

WhiteDragon coffin dodger at work, I managed to be fully loaded after a three day tedious wait all the block data for the /monero-gui-v0.17.1.9
Not pain free with a couple of restarts, all from scratch.
On shutting down the wallet had to kill the background demon with a Ctrl C, otherwise the PC was more or less locked out for normal work.
On restarting the /monero-gui-v0.17.1.9/monero-wallet-gui it took a while for the syncing to restart and in the lower left of the wallet I have:-

Wallet is synchronised
Daemon is synchronised(87656)

then it flips to

Waiting for daemon to sync
Daemon blocks remaining:     2224076

The error reports are
E Blocks start before blockchain offset: 0 2265000
E !m_blockchain.is_in_bounds(current_index).
THROW EXCEPTION: error::out_of_hashchain_bounds_error

Seems like it is trying to download the whole damned data in full again - time to pull the plug!
Thanks for any help/pointers -> WhiteDragon

Answer (score 0):

On a bit of digging found that the daemon had ignored the /Homedirectory/.bitmonero/lmdb that took 3 days to create. On restarting the gui the daemon began to re-create in total the data in /Homedirectory/Monero/monero-gui-v0.17.1.9/lmdb - it had stuffed 2gig already by time I pulled the plug. I cp'd the .bitmonero/lmdb content to this new location that had magically appeared and was able to resync the gui.  It would help if the daemon had an address or environment variable where to find the data.mdb rather find it chuntering off on it's own. Need more Noddy guide(s) for Newbies.
PS.
even a disk to disk copy of 106 gig takes nearly an hour to complete.

Follow up:- On checking with monerod --help   noted that /Homedirectory/.bitmonero is the default location for the database - hmmm, finger trouble at work - yes I had stupidly in the gui Settings/node section entered the download directory for the Blockchain location - DOH! Deleted my entry such that it was marked as default. Now I can remove the extra 106gig copy of the database. On restart the re-sync took a few minutes to complete and was in the correct location of /HomeDirectory/.binmonero

Time for a cup of coffee now that is fixed!

Comment: coould you explainn to me how you solved your problem? The electricity broke at my apartment after downloading more than 70GB and I don't want to start from scratch since it's taken almost a week to download the data. Now everytime I want to start the monero daemon it brakes and does nothing... should I start at a new location and then copy the 70 GB from the previous download?